# when to use function() , function or () => function(callback)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, ecmascript-6

I have been searching for a while for a good explanation so its all clear to me. 
Example:

```
<Char click={()=>this.onDeleteHandler(index)}/>
```

vs

```
<Char click={this.onDeleteHandler()}/>
```

vs

```
<Person changed={(event) => this.nameChangedhandler(event, person.id)} />
```

and

```
<Char click={this.onDeleteHandler}/>
```

regarding the third code , here is the property called:

```
nameChangedhandler = (event, id) => {
const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p => {
  return p.id === id;
});

// copying the person with the right index
const person = {
  ...this.state.persons[personIndex]
};

// Assigning new name to this person
person.name = event.target.value;

// copying array of persons, then manipulating the correct object of person by using the index
const persons = [...this.state.persons];
persons[personIndex]= person;

this.setState({
  persons: persons
});
```

}

some aspects are clear to me, but definitely not 100%! 
So if you can provide me with an explanation, link or similar that would be great!

thanks!

Comment: The third one is just invalid.

Comment: and the fourth one (a bare function reference) is rarely correct.

Comment: And the second one won't work, the function is called right away.

Comment: @Alnitak: why rarely correct?

Comment: because when that bare function reference is invoked it'll no longer refer to the right `this`

Answer (score 7):

```
<Char click={()=>this.onDeleteHandler(index)}/>
```

It passes anonymous function as a callback which - when clicked - triggers `onDeleteHandler` with extra `index` parameter (which has to be defined in the scope before).

```
<Char click={this.onDeleteHandler()}/>
```

It passes result of `onDeleteHandler()` as a callback - probably a bad idea - `onDeleteHandler` function has to return another function that will be invoked on click.

```
<Person click={changed={(event) => this.nameChangedhandler(event, person.id)} />
```

Looks invalid - will result with syntax error.

```
<Char click={this.onDeleteHandler}/>
```

Similar to the first example but doesn't take custom parameters. Default click event will be passed as a first argument for `onDeleteHandler`

Comment: <Person click={changed={(event) => this.nameChangedhandler(event, person.id)} />

this works and is valid ( using react). Thanks for the other explanations though :)

Comment: @Michael: [It's not valid](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwBQpgTgzg9gdgAgMYBsCWSDWBeA3kgCwEM4BzMAEzwAowA3MOAFwEoFsA-BJgtKAOjhEAtmADCxMpUkUUkWg2YAaBAAdIsOPzQUWAXwQB6DkA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=react&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=).

Comment: @hsz: to clarify the one that looks invalid I will add some more of the code: 
nameChangedhandler = (event, id) => {
    const personIndex = this.state.persons.findIndex(p => {
      return p.id === id;
    });
    // copying the person with the right index
    const person = {
      ...this.state.persons[personIndex]
    };
    // Assigning new name to this person
    person.name = event.target.value;

    ( more code ... ) 
  }

Comment: @Michael: It's irrelevant what  `nameChangedhandler` is. `click={changed={...}}` is simply not valid code here.

Answer (score 1):

The whole question seems to boil down to what the difference between `func` and `func()` and `() => func()` is. It has nothing to do specifically with React.

If I have a function

```
function func() {
  console.log(42);
}
```

Then I can reference the function object itself via `func`. This is useful if I need to *pass the function to another function*, e.g. `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(func, 1000); // calls func after 1000ms
```

`setTimeout` expects a function that it can call after the provided timeout.

Similarly in React, `click`, `change` etc are all props that expect to be passed a function that is called when the event happens.

---

`func()` on the other hand *calls the function*. This needs to be done if you actually need to call function right then and there.
This implies that if I do

```
setTimeout(func(), 1000);
```

then I would call `func` first and *pass its return value* to `setTimeout` (i.e. *I* call `func` now, `setTimeout` doesn't call it later). So this is usually incorrect *unless* `func` returns a function itself and its really the return value I want to pass to the other function.

---

`() => func()` is just a new function that only calls `func`. For all intends and purposes it is equivalent to `func`:

```js
function func() {
  console.log(42);
}

const anotherFunc = () => func();

func();
anotherFunc();
```

And of course if `func` expects an argument then I have to pass it along when wrapping it in another function, which is what `x => func(x)` does.

---

The other part is how functions assigned to object properties and `this` work. In short, what `this` refers to inside a (non-arrow) function depends on how the function is *called*. Doing

```
this.foo();
// or
var bar = this.foo;
bar();
```

produces two different results because `this.foo()` and `bar()` are two different ways to call the function. For more info see [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: King: thank you so much for this explanation. Just one more clarification: 
you say if I have an argument I want to pass in an Arrow function it looks like this: x => func(x) which makes completely sense. What is this then: () => func(x). Thanks again! :)

Comment: Pretty much the same expect that `x` must be defined somewhere else in the lexical scope of the function. Example: `var x = 42; function foo() { console.log(x);};  foo();`. This is what we usually call a *closure*. If `x` is not declared you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would make use of inline arrow functions when you need to bind he handler to the context or to provide custom parameters

In

```
<Char click={()=>this.onDeleteHandler(index)}/>
```

`onDeleteHandler` is bound to the context where `Char` is rendered and is passed a custom parameter `index`. Since a new function is returned to `click` , it can be executed from within `Char` like `this.props.click()`

```
<Char click={this.onDeleteHandler()}/>
```

Here the `onDeleteHandler` is evaluated and the value is returned to the `click` prop

```
<Person click={changed={(event) => this.nameChangedhandler(event, person.id)} />
```

Here the syntax is invalid, it should probably be

```
<Person changed={(event) => this.nameChangedhandler(event, person.id)} />
```

In which case, it takes the default parameter and pass it along with the custom parameter to `nameChangedHandler` and it also performs binding

```
<Char click={this.onDeleteHandler}/>
```

just assigns the reference of `onDeleteHandler` to `click` and whenever you invoke `click`, `onDeleteHandler` will be called with the parameters that you pass while invoking click and the context within `onDeleteHandler` will refer to the context from where it is invoked unless you bind `onDeleteHandler` using arrow function or in constructor

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)